# Runtime Chart on Web using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts

I want to make runtime chart on the web using ASP.net c#.

However, everytime update panel triggered by the timer_tick event(1 second), whole the datapoints are going lost.

Here is the code snippet aspx;

```
<ig:WebScriptManager ID="WebScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </ig:WebScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
             StackedareaChart Content here ...
```

Here is c# code;

```
int maxDataPoints=60;

   public void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {    
     foreach (NumericSeries series in this.MonitorChart.Series)
     {
       for (int i = 0; i <= maxDataPoints; i++)
        {
            NumericDataPoint nd = new NumericDataPoint(0, string.Empty, false);
            series.Points.Add(nd);
        }

    if (series.Points.Count >= maxDataPoints)
        {
        series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }   
     if (series.Label == "User I/O")
        {
            getCurrentValues(cmdUserIO, series);
        }
    else if (series.Label == "Administrative")
        {
            getCurrentValues(cmdAdministrative, series);
        }   
}
}

      public void getCurrentValues(string cmdOrcl, NumericSeries series)
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdOrcl, con);
    con.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

    if (dr.HasRows == false)
    {
        NumericDataPoint nd = new NumericDataPoint(0, string.Empty, false);
        series.Points.Add(nd);
    }

    else if (dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        drCurrent = dr.GetDouble(0) / (timeInvertal * 100);

        if (cmdOrcl == cmdUserIO)
        {
            NumericDataPoint nd = new NumericDataPoint(drCurrent - tempCPU, string.Empty, false);
            series.Points.Add(nd);
            tempCPU = drCurrent;
        }
        else if (cmdOrcl == cmdAdministrative)
        {
            NumericDataPoint nd = new NumericDataPoint(drCurrent - tempAdministrative, string.Empty, false);
            series.Points.Add(nd);
            tempAdministrative = drCurrent;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Is this ASP.Net Web Form? If so, please remove `asp.net-mvc` tag. Please upload a sample code, so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: You are right. I edited in that should be done.

Comment: Why are you posting the same question twice?